# How to exclude the program startup code (__name__ == "__main__") from being included in pytest coverage reports?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest, code-coverage

We have several small scripts in our project that take some command-line arguments. For example:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--branch")
    command_line_args = parser.parse_args()
    if not command_line_args.branch:
        raise Exception
    main(command_line_args.branch)
```

we are not really interested in unit-test this. However, this impacts our coverage report, is there a way to exclude the `if __name__ == "__main__"` from unit-tests using pytest?

Comment: It's not really about unit testing. Coverage is a layer on top. I believe the updated title reflects the intent better.

Comment: FWIW, you might want to recognize that there is code there that could have bugs, and tests for it could be valuable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a comment, like this:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":  # pragma: no cover
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()    
    ...
```